# creating and copy/duplicating a select/option list menu with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `select` list menu:

```
<label>
    <select name="select" id="select1">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
</label>
```

I want to duplicate it with the exact informations dynamically. I can do that by creating a `select` element and copying the `innerHTML` from the first `select`. (I also generate a table row which my `select` is going to be on, but it's not important):

```
var selectt = document.createElement("select");
selectt.setAttribute("name", "select"+counter);
selectt.setAttribute("id", "select"+counter);
selectt.onchange = function() {sellcalculate(counter); 

cell3.appendChild(selectt);
document.getElementById("select"+counter).innerHTML=document.getElementById("select1").innerHTML;
```

It works fine on Firefox, but IE just creates the select but wouldn't copy the options.

My second question is: how can I add an onchange event to the created element?

```
 selectt.onchange = function(){sellcalculate(counter)};
```

This doesn't seems to work.

here is the compelete function after edit  function and solving the ie problem :

```
function addRow(tableID) {
    var counter = document.getElementById('rowcounter').value;
    counter++;
    document.getElementById('rowcounter').value = counter;
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
    var cell = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var element2 = document.createElement("input");
    element2.type = "text";
    element2.id = "amount" + counter;
    element2.onchange = function () {
        sellcalculate(counter)
    };
    cell2.appendChild(element2);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var selectt = document.createElement("select");
    selectt = document.getElementById("select1").cloneNode(true);
    selectt.setAttribute("name", "select" + counter);
    selectt.setAttribute("id", "select" + counter);
    selectt.onchange = (function (cntr) {
        return function () {
            sellcalculate(cntr);
        };
    })(counter);
    cell3.appendChild(selectt);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't test in IE right now, but try using `.cloneNode()` instead to create the new element.

```
var selectt = document.getElementById("select1").cloneNode(true);

selectt.setAttribute("name", "select"+counter);
selectt.setAttribute("id", "select"+counter);
selectt.onchange = (function( cntr ) {
    return function() { sellcalculate(cntr); };
})( counter );

cell3.appendChild(selectt);
```

The `true` argument passed to `.cloneNode` makes it a deep clone (all descendants).

Also, I assumed you want the `onchange` handler to reference the *current* value of `counter` instead of a potentially different future value. As such, I scoped the current value using a new function invocation.

Now whatever the value of `counter` is when this code runs will be the value passed to `sellcalculate()`.

Comment: thanx it's working in ie now . but my onchange is still a problem it's the same on the all of the created select lists it uses cloned handler on all of them i've updated my code take a look pleas

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery .clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) like this:

```
$('#select1').clone().attr({'id':'select'+counter, 'name':'select'+counter}).appendTo('cell3Selector');
```

Test page [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ravan/Qpy3p/).

Comment: There's no indication in the question that OP is using jQuery.