# html drop box display values from one source

Tags: html, drop-down-menu

I am currently creating a order form, and there are several options where I have a dropbox with the values 1-8 in them. For each drop box I have to use the following code

```
<select name="mydropdownbox">
                <option value=""> 0 </option>
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
                <option>4</option>
                <option>5</option>
                <option>6</option>
                <option>7</option>
                <option>8</option>
            </select>
```

I have to use the same code each time I have a new item added to the form. I was wondering if there is a way to make the drop down boxes all use the same set of values so I dont have a bunch of repeat code in my html page.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to duplicate the select list (drop box)?
If yes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6514943/creating-and-copy-duplicating-a-select-option-list-menu-with-javascipt

Comment: I'm not sure if thats the same thing I am looking for.. Say if I had 10 drop box's I was hoping I could have one place in my code where I could define <options> 0-8 and then instead of doing it for all 10 drop box's just pass those drop box's the one set of defined options else where in my code.... I hope this makes sense.

Comment: it is definitely not possible using only html. but surely this is possible if you use javascript. add some tags to your questions. i mean <javscript> and <jquery>

Comment: @HurkNburkS:  you are asking something like UserControl available in ASP.NET; i think HTML do not give you such an option of reusability

Comment: bugger.. okay well thank you very much for helping me... I will just leve it then I guess.. its just I could save so many lines of code if i could just create one set of options and just refrence it for each dropdown box.. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done with HTML only, since HTML isn't a scripting language, so you can't do loops to avoid repeating.

You have two options:

- Use a server side language which produces complete HTML. Note this will be a bit more server-intensive, and users will have to download full HTML code
- Use javascript. This will be a bit more client-intensive, and you will save bandwidth. The possible problem is that some users could have JS disabled.

The JavaScript way is easy to implement using HTML5 [`<template>`](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/template/) element:

JS:

```
var content = document.getElementById('dropdown-template').content;
for(var i=0; i<10; ++i) {
    document.body.appendChild(document.importNode(content, true));
}
```

HTML:

```
<template id="dropdown-template">
    <select name="mydropdownbox">  <!-- ... -->   </select>
</template>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2D6NE/)